# NodeJS : Async module and order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I have a little problem using nodejs with the Async lib.

Here is the issue : I'm trying to get the links from a website and display them in an array.
The problem is, when i run the script, it displays the second function first and then the first function.
Why ? :/

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var async = require("async");
var homepage = "http://xxx";
var start = [];

async.series([

function(callback){
    //Request to website
    var myVisit = request(homepage,function(err,resp,body){
        if(err) throw err

            $ = cheerio.load(body);
    ////Get all the links in the list
            $('aside ul li').each(function(){
                start.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
            });
            console.log(start);
    });

    callback(null, myVisit);
},
    /// Dummy function 
function(callback){
    var display = console.log("Blabla");
    callback(null,display);
}


]);

///Outputs 'Blabla' and then the links array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the async callback function at the wrong place in the first function. 
The request function call is non blocking and the code moves to the next line. For async series as soon as the callback of async is called it leaves the function and starts executing the next function.

Possible solution will be putting **callback(null, myVisit)** inside the callback of request. You wait for request function to return result. Get all the links and then call the callback of async

Comment: This is not the problem. The `request(..)` function declaration and passing its reference to the `callback(null, myVisit);` is the proper way to do it. What @user2914878 didn't think of is the detached and defered form in which `myVisit` will report its results (with its `console.log(start);`). My answer explains it in more detail.

Comment: I thought he wants to enforce that first function completes and req(...) gives its result before next function is called. So  I suggested this solution which kind of makes the request blocking.

Comment: Actually, i do want to enforce the first function to finish first and then proceed to the second function. @ankit042 you solution did work.

I put the callback at the end of the request.

Comment: Well, thank you @user2914878 for wasting our time trying to help. Next time, please first get it straight what you **actually want** to achieve and then **articulate it properly**.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, even though the `async.series` guarantees the order it will call the tasks/functions, it doesn't mean it can guarantee the results order if the result was produced by another **asynchronuos function call**.

If you used it like this:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        console.log('one');
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('two');
    }
]);
```

You would get this:

```
one
two
```

But specifying an async `request(...)` means it will `log` only after *that* function finishes.

You can test it like this:

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var async = require("async");
var homepage = "http://xxx";
var start = [];

async.series([

function(callback){
    console.log('1st async task');
    //Request to website
    var myVisit = request(homepage,function(err,resp,body){
        if(err) throw err

            $ = cheerio.load(body);
    ////Get all the links in the list
            $('aside ul li').each(function(){
                start.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
            });
            console.log(start);
    });

    callback(null, myVisit);
},
    /// Dummy function 
function(callback){
    console.log('2nd async task');
    var display = console.log("Blabla");
    callback(null,display);
}


]);
```

Now you should get this output:

```
1st async task
2nd async task
Blabla
[links]
```